# How to open android gallery app from React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-linking

I am having trouble while opening the gallery using linking on android devices. It works perfectly on iOS.
I am using this.

```
openPhotos = () =>{
switch(Platform.OS){
  case "ios":
    Linking.openURL("photos-redirect://");
  break;
  case "android":
    Linking.openURL("content://media/internal/images/media");
  break;
  default:
    console.log("Could not open gallery app");
 }
}
```

A pop is shown on android, and after selecting photos, a black screen appears.[here is the screenshot for the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nd8b.jpg)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker

Comment: My motive was to open the gallery to view recently clicked images for a camera application and reduce the code implementation. It seems that I have to use this package and design a gallery component myself. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker

This package have methods you can use to open gallery and select an image!
This method `launchImageLibrary(options?, callback)` is useful for this.

Here an example for using this method:

```
RNImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({}, (response) => {
  if (response.didCancel) {
    // user cancel image selection
  } else if (response.error) {
    // error
  } else {
    // her you access the image with response object
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({
      image: {
        uri: response.uri,
      },
    });
  }
});
```